# SQL Query how to summarize students record by date?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a following table Students

```
Id  StudentId       Subject         Date          Grade

1   001     Math        02/20/2013  A

2   001     Literature  03/02/2013  B

3   002     Biology     01/01/2013  A

4   003     Biology     04/08/2013  A

5   001     Biology     05/01/2013  B

6   002     Math        03/10/2013  C
```

I need result into **another table** called `StudentReport` as shown below. This table is the cumulative report of all students records in chronological order by date.

```
Id StudentId       Report

1   001     #Biology;B;05/01/2013#Literature;B;03/02/2013#Math;A;02/20/2013

2   002     #Math;C;03/10/2013#Biology;A;01/01/2013

3   003     #Biology;A;04/08/2013
```

Comment: Please specify the RDBMS that you are targeting by adding the appropriate tag (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, etc.). There may be answers that take advantage of language or product features that are not universally supported. Also, by tagging it with a specific RDBMS, your question may receive attention from people better suited to answer it.

Comment: You want the course and grade in a big concatenated string? Why? Based on your table structure it looks to me like you already have exactly the data you need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically you would not store this data in a table, you have all the data needed to generate the report.

SQL Server does not have an easy way to generate a comma-separated list so you will have to use `FOR XML PATH` to create the list:

```
;with cte as
(
  select id, 
    studentid,
    date,
    '#'+subject+';'+grade+';'+convert(varchar(10), date, 101) report
  from student
) 
-- insert into studentreport
select distinct 
  studentid,
  STUFF(
         (SELECT cast(t2.report as varchar(50))
          FROM cte t2
          where c.StudentId = t2.StudentId
          order by t2.date desc
          FOR XML PATH (''))
          , 1, 0, '')  AS report
from cte c;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/58bdd/2) (includes an insert into the new table). Give a result:

```
| ID | STUDENTID |                                                          REPORT |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 10 |         1 | #Biology;B;05/01/2013#Literature;B;03/02/2013#Math;A;02/20/2013 |
| 11 |         2 |                         #Math;C;03/10/2013#Biology;A;01/01/2013 |
| 12 |         3 |                                           #Biology;A;04/08/2013 |
```

Comment: +1 Did it in MySQL, but you were faster with the TSQL translation :)

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I worked on both while waiting to see what database it was.  MySQL is much easier to do this in.

Comment: Yeah, group_concat in TSQL is a mess :-/

Comment: Thank you everyone for all the good ideas. BlueFeet, thank you very much worked like a charm. I appreciate your help.  Thank

Comment: @bluefeet as I told in the earlier comment your query worked well thank you. Now I came to know that students table has around 25 millions :) records. I want to create few indexes. Is it good idea to create indexes on all the columns or just studentid & date. Any suggestion?

Comment: @Think indexes should be added, my suggestion would be to post a new question with the create table details and the explain plan for the query, then you will get help on that question. :)

Comment: @bluefeet created another Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16425954/how-to-improve-performance-of-this-query

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to insert the data from 'Students' into 'Student Report', try:

```
INSERT INTO StudentReport (ID, StudentID, Report)
SELECT ID, StudentID, '#' + subject + ';' + grade + ';' + date AS report
FROM Students
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using **CTE**.Improve performance.

[**`FOR XML`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178107%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

```
(select 
min(ID) as ID,
StudentId,
STUFF((select ', '+'#'+s2.Subject+';'+s2.Grade+';'+convert(varchar(25),s2.Date)
from student s2
where s2.StudentId=s1.StudentId
FOR XML PATH (''))
,1,2,'') as report
into t
 from student s1
group by StudentId)
;

select * from t
```

Where **t** would be new **Table Name** which doesn't exists in **DataBase**.

**[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f197a/4)**