# How to improve performance of this query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, rdbms

With reference to [SQL Query how to summarize students record by date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16343294/sql-query-how-to-summarize-students-record-by-date) I was able to get the report I wanted.

I was told in real world the students table will have 30 Millions of records. I do have index on (StudentID, Date). Any suggestions to improve the performance or is there a better way to build the report ?

Right now I have the following query

```
;with cte as
(
  select id, 
    studentid,
    date,
    '#'+subject+';'+grade+';'+convert(varchar(10), date, 101) report
  from student
) 
-- insert into studentreport
select distinct 
  studentid,
  STUFF(
         (SELECT cast(t2.report as varchar(50))
          FROM cte t2
          where c.StudentId = t2.StudentId
          order by t2.date desc
          FOR XML PATH (''))
          , 1, 0, '')  AS report
from cte c;
```

Comment: Where is the execution plan?

Comment: ;with cte as
(
  select id, 
    studentid,
    date,
    '#'+subject+';'+grade+';'+convert(varchar(10), date, 101) report
  from student
) 
-- insert into studentreport
select distinct 
  studentid,
  STUFF(
         (SELECT cast(t2.report as varchar(50))
          FROM cte t2
          where c.StudentId = t2.StudentId
          order by t2.date desc
          FOR XML PATH (''))
          , 1, 0, '')  AS report
from cte c;

Comment: A date range would mean fewer records are being processed.  That would improve performance.  It would probably make your report more relevent as well.

Comment: @Dan Bracuk Date range. I am not following. Could you please explain more ?

Comment: @Think that is not the execution plan, that is the query.  Run this before your query:  SET SHOWPLAN_TEXT ON; GO

Comment: @Think Instead of querying 30 million rows, can you include a `where date >= '2012-01-01' and date <= '2012-12-31'` in the initial CTE? This would minimize how many rows you are querying. Do you really need to generate this report for 30 million students at the same time?

Comment: Why not assemble the report in the application rather than using the FOR XML PATH('') hack?

Comment: @Dan Yes I need report (aggregate) for all students at the same time.

Comment: @Think why would you have requirements that make you grab this report for all students for all of time. The report would be heinously unreadable.

Comment: @Zane we take this report and get fed into another application. Execution plan is huge i cant  paste it here also it has our DB name details. I have replace those :)

Comment: @Think get SQL Sentry's [Plan Explorer](http://www.sqlsentry.net/plan-explorer/sql-server-query-view.asp) -> it has an anonymize feature. Use that and you'll have a clean plan to show, and also a different view of where the problems are in the plan ;).

Comment: @Marian Thank you. SQL Sentry's is  a very handy tool.

Comment: @Think you essentially feed all of your data over to an app? How often do you do this?

Comment: @Zane right now once a month.

Comment: @Think Can't you just ship them the records that are new from last month.

Comment: @Zane Actually this data is being captured from another system. Right now when we get data for one month it is having 30 millions of records. We will always process it only once (maybe once a month or once in a quarter or once a year) and build report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing the execution plan, it's not really possible to write an optimized SQL statement so I'll make suggestions instead.

Don't use a cte as they often don't handle queries with large memory requires well (at least, in my experience).  Instead, stage the cte data in a real table, either with a materialized/indexed view or with a working table (maybe a large temp table).  Then execute the second select (after the cte) to combine your data in an ordered list.

The number of comments to your question indicates that you have a large problem (or problems).  You're converting tall and skinny data (think integers, datetime2 types) into ordered lists within a strings.  Try to think instead in terms of storing in the smallest data formats available and manipulating into strings until afterward (or never).  Alternatively, give serious thought into creating an XML data field to replace the 'report' field.

If you can make it work, this is what I would do (including a test case without indexes).  Your mileage may vary, but give it a try:

```
create table #student (id int not null, studentid int not null, date datetime not null, subject varchar(40), grade varchar(40))

insert into #student (id,studentid,date,subject,grade)
select 1, 1, getdate(), 'history', 'A-' union all
select 2, 1, dateadd(d,1,getdate()), 'computer science', 'b' union all
select 3, 1, dateadd(d,2,getdate()), 'art', 'q' union all
--
select 1, 2, getdate() , 'something', 'F' union all
select 2, 2, dateadd(d,1,getdate()), 'genetics', 'e' union all
select 3, 2, dateadd(d,2,getdate()), 'art', 'D+' union all
--
select 1, 3, getdate() , 'memory loss', 'A-' union all
select 2, 3, dateadd(d,1,getdate()), 'creative writing', 'A-' union all
select 3, 3, dateadd(d,2,getdate()), 'history of asia 101', 'A-'

go

select      studentid as studentid
            ,(select s2.date as '@date', s2.subject as '@subject', s2.grade as '@grade' 
            from #student s2 where s1.studentid = s2.studentid for xml path('report'), type) as 'reports'
from        (select distinct studentid from #student) s1;
```

I don't know how to make the output legible on here, but the resultset is 2 fields.  Field 1 is an integer, field 2 is XML with one node per report.  This still isn't as ideal as just sending the resultset, but it is at least one result per studentid.

Comment: This is my thinking too - a CTE is probably slowing this down creating an extra step that isn't needed.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion. I did remove and wrote the query directly. Still it's longer time but better than CTE.